# Environment setup in GIT repository

Tags: eclipse, git

Need small help related to the environment setup in a Git repository. Actually I created a Bitbucket account and I am trying to connect Eclipse and Git. But unfortunately I am not able to find Git in Windows. Could you please help me out on this?

I am using the Neon version of the Eclipse SDK.

Comment: install git bash for windows

Comment: Eclipse has built-in Git support via EGit: http://www.eclipse.org/egit/ (no Git command line tool required)